# Can't ping other machines at Linux VPN PPTP server's local lan from outside

Tags: linux, vpn, sles, pptpd, sles11

Before anything else, hello guys, this is the first time I ask for something here so I hope someone can give me a hand, please look at the following network diagram:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------                      
VPN Server              Webserver
(SuSE SLES11)              |
     |                      |               
     ------- VPN LAN -------- 
     |
   Router with Unique IP (With Port Forwarding rules set and VPN through enabled)    
     |
PPTP connection over Internet
     |
Workstation
(PC or Laptop with Windows)
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the idea is for the workstation to connect to the PPTP Server and then be able to access a Web Application on the Webserver, right now I have the PPTP server configured and the VPN works, I can connect to the SLES11 server with no problems from the workstation and I can ping it and everything works fine but if I try to ping the Webserver from the workstation, I can't reach it, I'm making a mistake somewhere but I don't see where, please note that I'm not a network expert and thus I'd greatly appreciate some specific guidance.

**Here is some info related to the IPs**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
*** SLES11 VPN Server has 2 Network cards:
-- eth0 (Internal Network)
IP:  192.168.210.5 
MASK: 255.55.255.0

-- eth1 (External Network)
IP: 192.168.1.105
MASK: 255.55.255.0

*** Webserver has 1 network card
-- eth0 (Internal Network)
IP:  192.168.210.221 
MASK: 255.55.255.0

*** Workstation
-- IP info once connection has been established to the VPN
PPP adapter Test VPN Connection:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Test VPN Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.210.110(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 189.209.208.181   (Defined as part of the PPTP Server options config script)
                                       189.209.127.244
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.210.220   (Defined as part of the PPTP Server options config script)
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

**I also defined the following within IP tables:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you need any piece of information from the PPTP server scripts please let me know, the thing is that I can actually connect to the VPN server and access its services and everything but after that I can't reach any other computer on that LAN.
Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance